# Are companies listed on the TSX Venture Exchange required to publish financial statements regularly?

Tags: stocks, canada, stock-exchanges, financial-statements, toronto-stock-exchange

The TSX Venture Exchange lists many small-cap and micro-cap companies. Are all these companies required by law to regularly make their financial statements available to the public? If so, do all these financial statements have to be published on SEDAR?

I am asking this question because I want to know whether or not the TSX Venture Exchange is like the US OTC stock market where disclosure requirements are lax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Periodic Filing and timely disclosure requirements for TSX-listed security issuers are detailed here:

https://www.tsx.com/listings/tsx-and-tsxv-issuer-resources/tsx-issuer-resources/continuous-disclosure

and here:

https://www.tsx.com/listings/tsx-and-tsxv-issuer-resources/tsx-venture-exchange-issuer-resources/tsx-venture-exchange-corporate-finance-manual/tsxv-corporate-finance-manual-policies

In short, companies must file quarterly financial statements within 45 days of the end of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd quarters of the fiscal year and within 90 days of the end of the financial year.  Any material information regarding the business of the company must be disclosed in a timely manner.

Note that "US OTC" is not a stock market - it's simply a place for quotation and reporting of over-the-counter trades on public companies.